# Is the UML class diagram the only notation / language to describe the structure of the system and what is the alternative?

Tags: uml, computer-science, modeling, software-design

What other languages or notations can be used to describe the structure of the system in addition to the classic UML class diagram?

Comment: Is there any reason you ask the same question again? It's still off topic. Use Google or ask elsewhere, please. And also please read the help about what questions are valid here.

Answer (score 0):

The structure of a system can be expressed in many flavors. For example:

- UML class diagram. That‘s the microscope: you can show the most detailed level if you wan to.
- [UML component diagram](https://www.visual-paradigm.com/guide/uml-unified-modeling-language/what-is-component-diagram/). That‘s the magnifying glasses: you can show higher level of interchangeable components.
- [UML composite structure](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/composite-structure-diagrams.html). That‘s the surgical view: you open up components to show the classes and parts which are inside.
- UML deployment diagram. It shows how components are materialized in artefacts (executables, libraries, configuration files) and distributed on processing nodes.
- [C4 model diagrams](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/C4_model). These allow to show the high level structure of a system in a light, simple an intuitive manner (mostly nested boxes), at the level of the context (system in its environment), the container (main platforms/servers/…) and the component level. It‘s simple, intuitive but less precise than UML, and this is why C4 relies on UML for lower levels that are more detailed (e.g. UML class diagrams).

There are many others, but UML is the convergence of many of these modeling techniques and covers the full spectrum of the structure.

Note that I didn‘t on purpose quote:

- ERD diagrams as these are not meant for modeling the full structure of a system, but only of domain information.
- [Archimate](https://sparxsystems.com/resources/gallery/diagrams/architecture/arc-archimate.html) which is another very rich language that has several features to describe system structure at a higher level, for architectural purpose, but is not suited for implementation level.